# CUDA support in clang

Tags: compiler-construction, llvm, clang

I am trying to convert a simple CUDA program to LLVM IR using Clang 3.0. The program is as follows,

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <clang/test/SemaCUDA/cuda.h>

 __global__ void kernfunc(int *a)
 {
    //kernel definition
    *a = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
 }

 int main()
 {
    int *h_a, *d_a, n;

    n = sizeof(int);
    h_a = (int*)malloc(n);
    *h_a = 5;

    cudaMalloc((void*)&d_a, n);
    cudaMemcpy(d_a, h_a, n, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    //kernel call
    kernelfunc<<<1,1>>>(d_a);
    cudaMemcpy(h_a, d_a, n, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    printf("%d", *h_a);
    return 0;
 }
```

What additional header files should be included? What part of the code is currently not supported by Clang 3.0?

Answer (score 1):

Your version of Clang is too old. Support for CUDA was [added in Clang 3.8](http://llvm.org/releases/3.8.0/tools/clang/docs/ReleaseNotes.html#cuda-support-in-clang). Once you upgrade, for a file named `hello.cu` the command is:

```
$ clang++ -o hello -I<CUDA install path>/samples/common/inc -L<CUDA install path>/<lib64 or lib> hello.cu -lcudart_static -lcuda -ldl -lrt -pthread
```

Refer to the [official documentation](http://llvm.org/releases/3.8.0/docs/CompileCudaWithLLVM.html) for more info.